# Dragable and Rotatable polygon

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
#import tkinter as tk
#from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

class obstaclelist:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.obsL=[]
        self.obsnums=0

    def setobnums(self,obamount):
        self.obsnums=obamount    #set number of obstacles

    def insertobs(self,newob):   #insert newly created obstacles
        self.obsL.append(newob)

class obstacleS:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.obs=[]
        self.configure=[]
        self.polynum=0
    def setobs(self,obS):       #set polygons of the obstacle
        self.obs.append(obS)
    def setconfigure(self,con):  #set initial configuration (x,y,angle)
        self.configure=con
    def setpolynum(self,numm):  #set number of polygons of an obstacle
        self.polynum=numm

class polygon:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.vertex=[]
        self.numvertex=0
    def setpoly(self,v):           #set vertexes of the polygon
        self.vertex=v
    def setvertexnum(self,numv):   #set number of vertex of a polygon
        self.numvertex=numv

class project:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.link=None
        self.layer=None
        self.root=Tk()
        self.frames =[]
        self.widgets =[]
        self.numPoly=0
        self.store=[]
        self.canvas=None
        self.halfwindow=200

    def RUN(self):
        #root=Tk()
        self.root.title("potential field")
        fullwindow=self.halfwindow*2
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.root,width=fullwindow,height=fullwindow,background='white',relief='raised',borderwidth=1)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(ALL))
        self.canvas.pack()

        FR= Frame(self.root).pack(side = "bottom")

        #btn1 = Button(FR, text = "Input", fg = "Orange",command=self.numObstacle).pack(side = "left")
        #btn2 = Button(FR, text = "Build", fg = "Red",command=self.add_polygon).pack(side = "left")
        #btn3 = Button(FR, text = "Robot", fg = "Blue",command=self.add_robot).pack(side = "left")

        self.root.mainloop()

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2

pg.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))

selected_rect = None  # Currently selected rectangle.
rectangles = []
for y in range(5):
    rectangles.append(pg.Rect(20, 30*y, 17, 17))
# As a list comprehension.
# rectangles = [pg.Rect(20, 30*y, 17, 17) for y in range(5)]

clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for rectangle in rectangles:
                    if rectangle.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        offset = Vector2(rectangle.topleft) - event.pos
                        selected_rect = rectangle
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                selected_rect = None
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected_rect:
                selected_rect.topleft = event.pos + offset

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        pg.draw.rect(screen, RED, rectangle)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I'm trying to create a dragable and rotatable obstacles on the panel. The obstacle consists of one or more polygons which are connected together, e.g L-shape obstacle consists of 2 rectangles. When the mouse drag the obstacles, the position information of polygons of the obstacle will be updated.

So far, I've tried to create a obstacle class, a polygon class, and a obstacle list class to record the initial position and angle of the obstacles. And I tried to create the panel using 'tkinter'.

Besides, I also see others using `Pygame` to implement the dragable rectangles. However, the code uses many attributes in `pygame.Rect`, such as `collidepoint`, which I'm not sure if it is also applicable to polygons as well.

Is there any suggestion that I can implement this idea? Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't mix `tkinter` with `pygame` - I would use only `tkinter` or only `pygame`. `tkinter` has methods to recognize clicked object and `move(offsetx, offsety)`. For `PyGame` you would have to build all from scratch. It is not hard and it can be nice to build it but it needs more work.

Comment: For Pygame, is there any method that I can create a polygon object and recognize if the mouse click is inside the polygon? e.g , For rectangle,  I can use pygame.Rect object and test if a point is inside a rectangle by pygame.Rect.collidepoint .

Comment: if you have surface with polygon then you can try to use [pygame.mask](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) to convert this image to bitmap mask and then check mouse position using [pygame.Mask.get_at](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.get_at). It is used also in [pygame.sprite.collide_mask](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is minimal example to drag `rect`, `oval` and `polygon` in `tkinter`.

I use canvas's functions to create object and I get object's `id` which I can use to assign mouse function.

For more complex opbject it would need something more complex.

**BTW:** For `rect`,`oval` it needs fill color to move when you click inside object. Without fill color you have to click in border to move object.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_press_tag(event, tag):
    '''start dragging'''
    global selected
    global previous_x
    global previous_y

    selected = tag
    previous_x = event.x
    previous_y = event.y

    print('press:', event, tag)

def on_release_tag(event, tag):
    '''end dragging'''
    global selected

    selected = None

    print('release:', event, tag)

def on_move_tag(event):
    '''during dragging'''
    global previous_x
    global previous_y

    #print(event.x, event.x)
    if selected:
        dx = event.x - previous_x
        dy = event.y - previous_y
        canvas.move(selected, dx, dy)
        previous_x = event.x
        previous_y = event.y

# --- main ---

# default values at start    
previous_x = None
previous_y = None
selected = None

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

items = [
    canvas.create_rectangle((100, 100, 120, 120), fill="blue"),
    canvas.create_rectangle((200, 200, 220, 220), fill="red"),
    canvas.create_oval((200, 100, 220, 120), fill='green'),
    canvas.create_polygon((300, 100, 320, 120, 340, 100)),
]

for item in items:
    canvas.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonPress-1>',   lambda event, tag=item: on_press_tag(event, tag))
    canvas.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event, tag=item: on_release_tag(event, tag))
    canvas.tag_bind(item, '<B1-Motion>', on_move_tag)

#canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_move_tag)


root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example which can move many objects

```
import tkinter as tk

class Item():

    def __init__(self, canvas, items):

        self.previous_x = None
        self.previous_y = None
        self.selected = None

        self.items = items

        for item in self.items:
            canvas.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonPress-1>',   lambda event, tag=item: self.on_press_tag(event, tag))
            canvas.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event, tag=item: self.on_release_tag(event, tag))
            canvas.tag_bind(item, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_move_tag)

    def on_press_tag(self, event, tag):
        self.selected = True
        self.previous_x = event.x
        self.previous_y = event.y

        print('press:', event, tag)

    def on_release_tag(self, event, tag):
        self.selected = False
        self.previous_x = None
        self.previous_y = None

        print('release:', event, tag)

    def on_move_tag(self, event):
        #print(event.x, event.x)
        if self.selected:
            dx = event.x - self.previous_x
            dy = event.y - self.previous_y

            for item in self.items:
                canvas.move(item, dx, dy)
            self.previous_x = event.x
            self.previous_y = event.y

# --- main ---


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

items = [
            canvas.create_oval((100, 80, 120, 100), fill='green'),
            canvas.create_rectangle((100, 100, 120, 120), fill="blue"),
            canvas.create_rectangle((100, 120, 120, 140), fill="red"),
        ]
Item(canvas, items)

items = [
            canvas.create_polygon((300,  60, 320,  80, 340,  60), fill='green'),
            canvas.create_rectangle((310, 80, 330, 100), fill='red', width=0),
            canvas.create_polygon((300, 120, 320, 100, 340, 120), fill='green'),
]
Item(canvas, items)

root.mainloop()
```

---

But using standard objects you can't rotate them. You would have to use polygon and create function which rotate it.

---

**EDIT:** I made example which can move polygon or move one of node (red rectangle) to change polygon

```
import tkinter as tk

class Item():

    def __init__(self, canvas, points):

        self.previous_x = None
        self.previous_y = None
        self.selected = None

        self.points = points

        # polygon
        self.polygon = canvas.create_polygon(self.points)
        canvas.tag_bind(self.polygon, '<ButtonPress-1>',   lambda event, tag=self.polygon: self.on_press_tag(event, 0, tag))
        canvas.tag_bind(self.polygon, '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event, tag=self.polygon: self.on_release_tag(event, 0, tag))
        canvas.tag_bind(self.polygon, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_move_polygon)

        # nodes - red rectangles
        self.nodes = []
        for number, point in enumerate(self.points):
            x, y = point
            node = canvas.create_rectangle((x-3, y-3, x+3, y+3), fill='red')
            self.nodes.append(node)
            canvas.tag_bind(node, '<ButtonPress-1>',   lambda event, number=number, tag=node: self.on_press_tag(event, number, tag))
            canvas.tag_bind(node, '<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event, number=number, tag=node: self.on_release_tag(event, number, tag))
            canvas.tag_bind(node, '<B1-Motion>', lambda event, number=number: self.on_move_node(event, number))

    def on_press_tag(self, event, number, tag):
        self.selected = tag
        self.previous_x = event.x
        self.previous_y = event.y

        print('press:', event, tag)

    def on_release_tag(self, event, number, tag):
        self.selected = None
        self.previous_x = None
        self.previous_y = None

        print('release:', event, tag)

    def on_move_node(self, event, number):
        '''move single node in polygon'''
        if self.selected:
            dx = event.x - self.previous_x
            dy = event.y - self.previous_y

            canvas.move(self.selected, dx, dy)
            self.points[number][0] += dx
            self.points[number][1] += dy

            # flatten list of points [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ] to list of numbers [x1, y1, x2, y2, ... ] 
            #coords = []
            #for item in self.points:
            #    coords += item
            coords = sum(self.points, [])
            #print('coords:', coords)

            # change points in polygons
            canvas.coords(self.polygon, coords)

            self.previous_x = event.x
            self.previous_y = event.y

    def on_move_polygon(self, event):
        '''move polygon and red rectangles in nodes'''
        if self.selected:
            dx = event.x - self.previous_x
            dy = event.y - self.previous_y

            # move polygon
            canvas.move(self.selected, dx, dy)

            # move red nodes 
            for item in self.nodes:
                canvas.move(item, dx, dy)

            # recalculate values in self.points
            for item in self.points:
                item[0] += dx
                item[1] += dy

            self.previous_x = event.x
            self.previous_y = event.y

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

points = [[100, 60], [210, 130], [100, 200], [340, 200], [230, 130], [340, 60]]
Item(canvas, points)

root.mainloop()
```

Polygon at start:

[image]

Polygon after moving nodes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, it helps a lot. Now, I'm trying to find the coordinate of the obstacle. I tried to add an input ' item ' in the function  ''on_release_tag''  , and then use the api canvas.coords(item) to find the coordinate of the obstacle. Yet, I found out that it only prints out the vertices of the lowest polygon, instead of the upper, lower, left and right bounds of the whole obstacle. The only way I can think of now is to record the bounds at the beginning and use the function to calculate it afterwards. Is there any better way to implement it? Thank you.

Comment: if you have many elements then you would have to use `coords` in `for`-loop to get all values and later use `min()`, `max()` on list of X and list of Y to find bounds. OR you can use [canvas.bbox()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) to get "bound box"

Comment: Thank you :) you just save my day :)

Comment: meanwhile I created example which moves polygon when you click somewhere inside polygon, or you can move only one of node to change polygon. See code and images in answer.

Comment: Thank you :)  BTW, I'm thinking if there is a way to convert the polygons drawn on the canvas to numpy array. It's like if it is drawn, then I fill in the pixel value with 255 in the numpy array, otherwise, I fill in zeros. If the pixel is half drawn, I still fill in with 255. I'm not sure if I can implement it by merely knowing every coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: I just found a possible way to implement this idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114005/skimage-polygon-function-why-does-the-last-vertice-repeats-in-the-polygon-docum

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't create bitmap with pixels which you could convert to numpy array. It is also problem to save it as `jpg` or `png` - and people use module [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to draw bitmap at the same time. `Pillow` creates image which you can also convert to numpy array. See [PIL.ImageDraw.polygon](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon) and later you can do [numpy.asarray(pillow_image)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)